# Un forecasting después del test

Tags: python

Tengo este código:

```
final_model = ExponentialSmoothing(df['Prov_SC'],seasonal='add').fit()
```

y me sale esto

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\statsmodels\tsa\holtwinters\model.py in __init__(self, endog, trend, damped_trend, seasonal, seasonal_periods, initialization_method, initial_level, initial_trend, initial_seasonal, use_boxcox, bounds, dates, freq, missing)
    253                 try:
--> 254                     self.seasonal_periods = freq_to_period(self._index_freq)
    255                 except Exception:

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\statsmodels\tsa\tsatools.py in freq_to_period(freq)
    811         freq = to_offset(freq)  # go ahead and standardize
--> 812     freq = freq.rule_code.upper()
    813 

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'rule_code'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-207-41586f69dc62> in <module>
----> 1 final_model = ExponentialSmoothing(df['Prov_SC'],seasonal='add').fit()

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\util\_decorators.py in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    197                 else:
    198                     kwargs[new_arg_name] = new_arg_value
--> 199             return func(*args, **kwargs)
    200 
    201         return cast(F, wrapper)

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\statsmodels\tsa\holtwinters\model.py in __init__(self, endog, trend, damped_trend, seasonal, seasonal_periods, initialization_method, initial_level, initial_trend, initial_seasonal, use_boxcox, bounds, dates, freq, missing)
    254                     self.seasonal_periods = freq_to_period(self._index_freq)
    255                 except Exception:
--> 256                     raise ValueError(
    257                         "seasonal_periods has not been provided and index "
    258                         "does not have a known freq. You must provide "

ValueError: seasonal_periods has not been provided and index does not have a known freq. You must provide seasonal_periods
```

Por qupe me sale lo último? El ValueError? Gracias por su ayuda.